# Using appropriate POSIX signals

Tags: linux, signals, posix

I am currently working on a project which has a daemon process that looks at a queue of tasks, runs those tasks, and then collects information about those tasks. In some cases, the daemon must "kill" a task if it has taken too long to run.

The explanation for SIGTERM is "termination signal" but that's not very informative. I would like to use the most appropriate signal for this.

What is the most appropriate POSIX signal number to use for telling a process "you took too much time to run so you need to stop now"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in control of the child processes, you can pretty much do as you please, but `SIGTERM` is the self-documenting signal for this. It asks a process to terminate, politely: the process chooses how to handle the signal and may perform cleanup actions before actually exiting (or may ignore the signal).

The standard way to kill a process, then, is to first send a `SIGTERM`; then wait for it to terminate with a grace period of, say, five seconds (longer if termination can take a long time, e.g. because of massive disk I/O). If the grace period has expired, send a `SIGKILL`. That's the "hard" version of `SIGTERM` and cannot be ignored, but also leaves the process no chance of neatly cleaning up after itself. Having to send a `SIGKILL` should be considered an issue with the child process and reported as such.

Comment: Although I'm in control of the child procs, I'm releasing my project for anyone to use, so I want to be as standard as possible with regards to using signals. Thanks for this info. I will SIGTERM, wait, then SIGKILL if not already done.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'll first send `SIGTERM` to a process. When the process recives this signal it is able to clean up some things an then terminate itself:

```
kill -15 PID_OF_PROCESS # 15 means SIGTERM
```

You can check if the process is still running by sending the `0` signal to it's pid.

```
kill -0 PID_OF_PROCESS # 0 means 0 :)
if [ "$?" == "0" ] ; then
    echo "the process is still running"
fi
```

However, you'll need some grace period to let the process clean up. If the process didn't terminated itself after a grace period, you kill it using `SIGKILL` this signal can't be handled by the process and the OS will terminate the process immediately.

```
kill -9 PID_OF_PROCESS # 9 means SIGKILL, means DIE!
```